# Can't display UIActivityIndicator on top of mapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

In my code, I initialize a UIActivityIndicator, and add it as a subview, but it never appears. What's going wrong?

```
-(void) update {

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityView.center=self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
    [activityView startAnimating];

    /** Stuff to  access to server, this stuff works correctly.*/
    [activityView stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: You never give it a chance to run since you stop it before the method returns.

Comment: Is update called on the main runloop? e.g. from a button press?

Comment: If the "stuff to access the server" happens asynchronously, you need to put the call to stop the animation within a completion block of that "server stuff." Make sure to use the main thread to update the UI if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

As you are `starting` and `stoping` the activity as same `runloop` so it will not get change to update the `UI`.You are doing all `server stuff` on same `synchronously` than you are blocking the `runLoop` and do not giving time to `activity` indicator to start.You should start server stuff on next `runLoop` so activity indicator will get time to start.So use `performSelector` with delay 0.0 it will start the `activity indicator` and than perform your server stuff on immediate next `runloop` and than stop the `activityInddicator`

```
-(void) update {

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityView.center=self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
    [activityView startAnimating];
    //Use performSelector with 0.0 so activity indicator starts  
    [self performSelector:@selector(thisWillStartAtNextRunLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

-(void)thisWillStartAtNextRunLoop{

    /** Stuff to  access to server, this stuff works correctly.*/
    [activityView stopAnimating];
}
```

**Edit** execute it on `main thread` as all UI updation must be on `main thread`
Try

```
-(void) update {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityView.center=self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
    [activityView startAnimating];
 });
    /** Stuff to  access to server, this stuff works correctly.*/
}
```

Comment: What is the `array` you put as argument in `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method? For someone who is quite new in obj-c it can be very confusing what you want to achieve. Can you be more precise when writing code as answer? In this case `-(void)thisWillStartAtNextRunLoop:(NSArray *)arg` should be used.

Comment: The code still doesn't seem to be working :(. Even if I take out the 'stopanimating' call, the activity view doesn't even appear.